# How to get rid of the volume charme?

Tags: windows-8.1

How can I get rid of the volume charme, that after a reboot suddenly shows up? I can't remeber what I might have changed...I dont' see any process that could refer to this overlay. Clicking on it doesnt help anything.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid thing... unplugging my USB headset made it go away. I am wondering why this out of the sudden showed up, as I always keep the headset plugged in... anyway...

Comment: Do you have volume control buttons on your headset? If yes, then "volume up" button was stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Press `Winkey + C` -> `Settings` -> `Change PC Settings` -> `Ease of Access` -> `Other Settings` -> `Show notifications for:` change to `5 seconds`

Comment: Thanks for replying. It is already set to 5 seconds...This volume control just keeps sitting on my desktop for ever